# Getting undefined behaviour while using functional components?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to populate html content i.e navigation dropdown menu using reactjs. I am getting undefined behaviour and I am not able to display dropdown menu navigation bar.

My code:

```
const Header = ({allnavitems, loading, SiteConfig, user}) => {


  if (loading) {
      return <div><p>Loading...</p></div>
  }

  console.log(allnavitems)
  if( allnavitems.links.length !== 0){
  return(

        <nav className="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
          <a className="navbar-brand" href="#">Crikit</a>
          <button className="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent"
            aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span className="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          </button>

          <div className="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
            <ul className="navbar-nav mr-auto">
              {allnavitems.map((allnavitems) => <Heading heading={allnavitems} />)}
            </ul>
            <form className="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
              <input className="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search"/>
                <button className="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
            </form>
          </div>
        </nav>
  )

}

};

const Heading = ({allnavitems}) => <NavDropdown links={allnavitems.links} heading={allnavitems.heading}/>

const NavDropdown = ({title, links}) => (
  <li className="nav-item dropdown">
    <a className="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button"
  data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
      {title}
    </a>
    <div className="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
      {links.map(({link='#', heading}) => <NavLink link={link} heading={heading}/>)}
    </div>
</li>
);

const NavLink = ({link='#', heading}) => (
  <a className="dropdown-item" href={link}>{heading}</a>
);
```

Above code doesn't display navigation bar.

On webpage I can see only Loading... in navigation bar and no navigation items why so ? (Check screenshot)

I want to display it something similar to this: (Check screenshot below)

[image]

Comment: Do you get any errors in the console? If `allnavitems` looks that way `allnavitems.links.length !== 0` won't work because `allnavitems` is an array.

Comment: @bamse If I do `console.log(allnavitems)` then I get following -> https://imgur.com/a/WPF6h6g

Comment: What happens if you use `if( allnavitems.length !== 0){` instead of `if( allnavitems.links.length !== 0){`?

Comment: @bamse I get `true` in console

Comment: @bamse As you can see I am mapping through `allnavitems` json data but I am getting undefined in console

Comment: @bamse Check the entire code -> http://jsfiddle.net/k1abm7xo/ I am getting error -> https://imgur.com/a/N4tZbfH I need to check if `links[ ]` array is zero or not I think that's why I am getting map of undefined

Comment: I've created a sandbox with your code: https://codesandbox.io/s/1wr8vkkxyl . There were some problems with the props you were passing to `Heading`. Fixing that renders the menu. This probably doesn't answer your question but it might be a step forward.

Comment: @bamse I am not able to understand what I was missing ? everything is looking same.

Comment: @bamse I think it should be allnavitems.links.length because if there are no links then what's the use of mapping an empty array

Comment: But `allnavitems` is an array and doesn't have a `allnavitems.links`. You could do `allnavitems[0].links.length` to check the first item in the array has links. `allnavitems` is an array of objects, each object containing a `links` property. I'll add another file to the sandbox and show you the changes I've made to make things work.

Comment: @bamse wait let me add my entire code I am getting error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177736/discussion-between-stone-rock-and-bamse).

Comment: @bamse Can you just copy this code -> https://jsfiddle.net/obrua945/1/ and paste it as an answer I will upvote :) Thanks for helping I did exactly as you said and it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your errors were caused by some mixed up prop names. 
In the final working example `Heading` component was removed. All it did was wrapping `NavDropdown` and passing the props to it. The problem was `Heading` wasn't getting the right props - it was expecting `links` and `heading` but was getting only `heading`.

I believe this is the code version that works:

```js
const Header = ({allnavitems, loading, SiteConfig, user}) => {
  

  if (loading) {
      return <div><p>Loading...</p></div>
  }

//  console.log(allnavitems)
  let navitems = allnavitems.filter( (value) => value.links.length !==0 )
  console.log(navitems)

  console.log(navitems[0].links)

  return(
      <header>
        <nav className="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
          <a className="navbar-brand" href="#">Crikit</a>
          <button className="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent"
            aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span className="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          </button>
    
          <div className="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
            <ul className="navbar-nav mr-auto">
              {navitems.map((navitems) => <NavDropdown heading={navitems.heading} links={navitems.links}/>)}
            </ul>
            <form className="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
              <input className="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search"/>
                <button className="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
            </form>
          </div>
        </nav>
      </header>
  )

};


//const Heading = (navitems) => <NavDropdown links={navitems.links} heading={navitems.heading}/>


const NavDropdown = ({heading, links}) => (
  <li className="nav-item dropdown">
    <a className="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button"
  data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
      {heading}
    </a>
    <div className="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
      {links.map(({link='#', heading}) => <NavLink link={link} heading={heading}/>)}
    </div>
</li>
);

const NavLink = ({link='#', heading}) => (
  <a className="dropdown-item" href={link}>{heading}</a>
);
```

[Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/1wr8vkkxyl?module=%2Fsrc%2Fnav.js) you can find the sandbox I tried the code in.